# Is there any dictionary or app that list/orders words by their parts of speech?

Tags: discussion

I want to expand my English vocabulary. So, I need a dictionary or mobile app that can show me the relevant words grouped by their parts of speech. But I am not able to find anything like it after hours of searching. Do anything like this exists?

Comment: You can download the Wiktionary database. Might need a bit of work though.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "_the relevant words_"? Do you want the words in each word class to be ordered according to their frequency of use?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about language or usage. It is about resources.

Comment: Googling search terms like *list of English nouns* gives lots of resources. I guess this is off topic, but it's also a bit vague to be able to recommend anything.

Comment: [english.se] is not primarily a language learning site, so people here will tend not to be as aware of language learning resources as at [ell.se] or [languagelearning.se]

Comment: Not in English. English lexical words (the ones with meanings, like _open_ and _house_) can be just about any part of speech. They're not marked like most European languages to distinguish between noun and verb inflection, and there's no gender agreement, so you can't tell nouns, adjectives, or verbs apart, except in a particular sentence. No one would publish an English dictionary like that.

Comment: I'm sure @JohnLawler is correct. But a concrete example [edited into your question](/posts/15603/edit) may help -- **what is it that you are actually trying to do?** A sentence like "I want to house him in a place that I pointed out to him" is probably too complex for such a resource, and I'm not sure how listing all English adverbs together would help (or *what* it would help you do).

Answer (score 4):

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/), a subscription resource, "Advanced Search" may do what you want. I'm unsure exactly what you're asking, but I expect that because you ask for "anything like this", my answer is an answer.

For example, I recently had occasion to find all [pronouns](https://www.oed.com/search?browseType=sortAlpha&case-insensitive=true&nearDistance=1&ordered=false&page=5&pageSize=20&pos=pronoun&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch) in *OED*. At the "Advanced Search" I selected "Pronoun" from the "Part of speech" drop-down list, then clicked the "Search" button. That produced a list of the 285 entries for pronouns in the *OED*. The list can be sorted by entry (alphabetical), *frequency*, or date of first known (by *OED*) attestation of the entry (that is, not necessarily the pronoun) in English.

Setting other parameters of the advanced search may allow you to restrict the list to entries for words you consider "relevant".